# How to replace every second newline with fullstops/periods in my CSV file?

Tags: csv, text, replace

I have an application which sends song lyrics to the Watson Tone Analyser and outputs the emotional score into a table. It also gives a score for every sentence in the lyrics and I will be using the maximum score of all the individual sentences to be announced to the user.

The issue with my CSV file is that the lyrics do not have full stops /periods(if American). [image: CSV file]

I tried replacing every "   " (double space) with full stops. This works for the application but creates extremely small sentences with some such as "Baby." being only one word long.

How can I replace every second or third double space in the CSV file with a fullstop?

Answer (score 0):

I could find no information on doing this within a 'find and replace' search on any program (I tried textEdit, excel and Numbers). The only way to do this is to write a program which I did not have time to do. I ended up just replacing every triple spacing with a full stop. These were less common than the double spacing so less fullstops occurred. This is not a great solution but it's the only one I could do with the time available.